# adjusting line size based on ouput screen in perl

Tags: string, perl, line

I am outputing some text on the screen in perl

However, I want to make sure that only 1 line fits on each screen line thus if I change screen the program would automatically adjust its output line size.

Is there a way to automatically do it without having user-interaction?

Thanks

Comment: Tell us more about your screen. Windows console? Unix?

Comment: unix console. 
i want it to be screen-independent if I move to another screen when run it will automatically adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -MTerm::ReadKey -E '($cols,$rows) = GetTerminalSize(); say "This screen has $rows rows and $cols columns."'
```

Answer (score 1):

On Unix/Linux you should be able to use the Term family of modules to get the current screen size. You can even hook SIGWINCH with it and respond to a terminal window resize event by adjusting your output.

http://search.cpan.org/modlist/User_Interfaces/Term